# Angular JS : Get last edited value on clicking cancel

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have textbox. when I edit the value and click on save then textbox is replaced with span tag having textbox value but when I edit again and click on cancel then , again the modified value is given to span instead of last edited value.

```
Here is [Codepen][1]
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WogGYX

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add separate two functions for saving and cancel, store the value into local variable, hope the you can understand the following code.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isEdit = false;

    var myText = 'Enter Group Name';//local variable to store the value

    $scope.myText = myText;

    $scope.show = function() {
      $scope.isEdit = true;
      $scope.myText = myText;
    }

    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.isEdit = false;
      myText = $scope.myText;

    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $scope.isEdit = false;
      $scope.myText = myText;
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="panel-heading padding_0_10px white_bg">
    <p class="padding_top_10">
      <input type="text" style="border: none; outline: none; width: 110px;" placeholder="Enter Group Name" data-ng-model="myText" data-ng-show="isEdit">
      <span data-ng-show="!isEdit" data-ng-bind="myText"></span>
      <span ng-click="save_group=true">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil margin_left_10 rearrange_text_color vertical_align_middle" data-ng-show="!isEdit" data-ng-click="show()"></i>
 </span>  <span class="pull-right gallery_title">01/10</span>
      <span ng-show="save_group">
 <span data-ng-click="save()" data-ng-show="isEdit">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Save</span><span data-ng-click="cancel()" data-ng-show="isEdit"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Cancel</span>
      </span>
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have update in codepen..please find previous Text

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNxgJR

also here put angular js code

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.isEdit = false;
    $scope.myText = "Enter Group Name";
    $scope.Previous=$scope.myText;
    $scope.show = function() {

      $scope.isEdit = true;
    }

    $scope.hide = function() {

      alert( $scope.Previous +' '+$scope.myText);
      $scope.Previous=$scope.myText;
      $scope.isEdit = false;
    }
  })
```

Comment: hello.. it's not working. When I write angular and click on save then the value is binded properly to span but when I modify the text box and click on **cancel** then the modified value is binded to span instead of last edited text.

Comment: last edited text on save button.. let say I have entered new group name and clicked on save . then that new group name should be binded to span. right.? now I edit the textbox again but this time i click on cancel so it means i dont want the new textbox value to be binded to span. I want last binded value